# An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json' Require stack

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli

`ng serve`
Response:
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'
Require stack:

I tried
`npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular`

Response:

````
npm WARN reify please re-try this operation once it completes
npm WARN reify so that the damage can be corrected, or perform
npm WARN reify a fresh install with no lockfile if the problem persists.
npm WARN reify invalid or damaged lockfile detected
npm WARN reify please re-try this operation once it completes
npm WARN reify so that the damage can be corrected, or perform
npm WARN reify a fresh install with no lockfile if the problem persists.
npm WARN reify invalid or damaged lockfile detected
npm WARN reify please re-try this operation once it completes
npm WARN reify so that the damage can be corrected, or perform
npm WARN reify a fresh install with no lockfile if the problem persists.```


Any Solution to solve. Let me know.
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just ran into this, my installation was interrupted midway and some packages were corrupted as a result.

The solution is pretty straightforward. Just delete the `node_modules` folder and the file `package-lock.json` then re-install the modules. The full command should be:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
```